# Error output from CocoaPods: ↳ Searching for inspections failed: undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Tags: flutter, dart, google-cloud-firestore, cocoapods

So, guys, this problem happening every time when i try to add a cloud_firebase in pubspec.yaml. My mac is working on intel processor, so the solution `sudo arch -x86_64 gem install ffi` is not working, `flutter clean` -> `pod install` not working to, also deleting Podfile.lock is not a solution :(. Have you any thinks about it?

[The error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YuFcg.png)

Answer (score 1):

So, if anyone tried all of the solutions from topics, but still not solved, this what i found and how i fixed the erorrs...

Try this from app package `rm -rf ~/.cocoapods/repos/trunk/`
This command will remove any local copies of the trunk repository, which we can see in error. After what go `flutter run`, it takes about 5-10 minutes to re-install all of the broken pods.

see docs https://blog.cocoapods.org/Repairing-Our-Broken-Specs-Repository/